# Python for mechanical engineers

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I'm a mechanical engineering undergraduate student and I want to start learning python. There are lots of online courses (free and paid) on the web but I don't know which is **the most useful for a mechanical engineer**.

Can someone help me to choose a suitable program for learning python?

And secondly, which syllabuses of python learning programs are necessary for a mechanical engineer?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a [resource-hunting question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/10/1832). Such questions are prone to becoming out-dated, and are therefore considered off-topic for this site.

Comment: True, but NMech's answer is excellent and *not* prone to becoming out-dated. Closed questions are not visible to most users, so I've voted to reopen.

Comment: If @JonathanRSwift's proposal to reopen succeeds, I might post an answer suggesting that OP proceeds (in part) by digging out CAD exercises s/he's previously undertaken in the course of his/her studies, and attempting to redo those exercises using Python as the programmatic control language for FreeCAD.

Answer (score 2):

I have been programming for many (many) years, in many different languages in many different problems. Python has been the latest in a long string of languages and platforms.   My experience is that Python is probably the language with the widest range of ecosystem and applications, with the possible exception of C/C++. As such there are many different ways and paradigms to program with Python. Depending on the problem domain, the "golden standard" of approaching a problem might be significantly different.  That might lead to a significant confusion. For me that was the biggest problem.

My suggestion is the following:

- follow any course which teaches you the basic language. I've started with edX's, but it really doesn't matter which one. If you can find a course that is relevant to your domain problem even better e.g. process dynamics, web programming with django, robotic programming with ROS, etc
- the next **and most importantant** thing, is once you have a basic understanding of the language **find a problem and start solving it**. If you run into a problem, just do a google search (most of the time it will lead you back to SE), figure out the solution and then proceed to the next problem.

In each little step you will "conquer" a bit more of the language. **You'll never get to stop learning something new:** the language and the scope of its applications are so vast that there will always be something new to learn.

Answer (score 0):

MIT’s [Into to Computer Science](https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-7) uses Python and is surprisingly gentle. I recommend it. It is computer science for non computer scientists which at MIT is usually engineering students. Complete free on edX.